# How to fix gearman PHP Warning: GearmanClient::do(): _client_do(GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) occured during gearman_client_run_tasks() on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, php, gearman

Getting an error PHP Warning:  GearmanClient::do(): _client_do(GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) occured during gearman_client_run_tasks() while running client script.

```
//------------worker.php
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

  $worker = new GearmanWorker();
  $worker->addServer();
  $worker->addFunction( "test" , "test_function" );
  while ($worker->work());
  function test_function( $job )
  {
    return strtoupper($job->workload());
  }
?>
//------------client.php
<?php
$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
$client->setTimeout(1000);
print "\n";
print $client->do( "test" , "this is a test" );
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nohub posix command to run the worker in the background

## run worker using below command

nohup /usr/bin/php worker.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &

## run client using below command

php client.php

Comment: Or: set_time_limit( 24192000 );